# Unable to stop navmeshagent for rotation before moving

Tags: unity, vector, scripting, quaternion, navmesh

I'm trying to get the NavMeshAgent to rotate before calculating a path and proceed walking.

I stumbled upon a thread that said this can be done by manually rotating the object first.

However, I am still stumped as to how to do this as my unit either a)refuses to move or b)moves, but does not stop to rotate.

Below is the code I've attempted.

```
void Update() {


    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            targetPosition = hit.point;
        }
    }

    if (transform.rotation != _lookRotation) //check if unit is in line with direction of hit.point
    {
        agent.Stop(); //stops the navmeshagent from moving.

        _direction = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized;
        _lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_direction);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, _lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);

    } //perform rotation
    else //else, if already in line, set path and walk.
    {

        agent.SetDestination(targetPosition);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) You need to update _lookRotation when the mouse is clicked or it never changes so your agent will never look at a new location.

Simple Coroutine Example:

```
IEnumerator RotateAgent(Quaternion currentRotation, Quaternion targetRotation) {

    IsRotating = true;
    while(current rotation != targetRotation) {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(currentRotation, targetRotation, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return 1;
    }
    IsRotating = false;
}
```

Then on Mouse Click:

```
StartCoroutine(RotateAgent(transform.rotation, _lookRotation);
```

And only do Agent.SetDestination if IsRotating = false;

Comment: In your second point, is there a way to get a definite "==" angle occur? At the end of the day, I'm just hoping to have the rotation happen over a constant speed and finally moving when it reaches said angle.

Comment: The best way would be a coroutine thats called on mouse click that will rotate the agent over a set time. Have it set a flag you check in the Update, if the flags not set then no rotation is going on and the agent can move.

Comment: StartCoroutine - [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Comment: Hi, I managed to do it by merging your code with a path reset function on the NavMeshAgent. Appreciate the help.